# Performance issue while upgrading apache-commons-beanutils jar

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

I am using apache-commons-beanutils jar. While upgrading from 1.7.0 to 1.9.2, I am facing serious performance issues. The issue is mainly due to newly added interface 'Resolver' in method getNestedProperty. Has anyone else faced the same or any related problem. Any suggestions or work around would be really helpful. Thank You.